# Vehicle 2 Vehicle Communication Questions

Tags: java, c++, database, gps, wireless

I have a rare opportunity to meet the man in charge of implementing vehicle 2 vehicle communication for the US Department of Transportation with 2 others in a few hours.

Do **YOU** have any questions for him?

I know this is a little outside the normal, but this is a 'reverse' thread and I felt he has some great knowledge on the subject that I want to share with this community.

I'll post his answers later today to his questions.

**Ask about V2V implementation, privacy issues, use cases, or if you've thought of a great way to use V2V and want me to share it with him, he can at least think about it.  He is in charge of panel that creates the standard. Or anything else...**

I'm more interested in sharing great uses for V2V if you can think of any... I'll give credit, promise... particularly because he may not hear them on a day to day basis.

Here's a good primer on the subject if you want to contribute something original.
http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/gadgets/news/4213544

Comment: This should probably be Community Wiki

Comment: Man, vehicles are communicating now?  Toyotas have enough trouble taking brake input from people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guy came and delivered a presentation.  Every question I had from you guys he covered.  If I didn't answer correctly, please let me know.

Most information can be found here: http://www.intellidriveusa.org/

Answer (score 1):

Retransmission:

Retransmission could greatly improve the lifetime of useful information.  By useful I mean stuff like "it's slick right here", or "cop right here".  A message that is continually retransmitted would long out original producer.

Using the black ice example.

north bound car x find black ice as GPS pos B.
car x passes southbound car y and transmits this information.  Car y is at GPS pos A and now  warns that it will soon be approaching GPS pos B and that it might be slick.
While at position B car y doesn't find it to be slick.
car y passes northbound car z at pos C and retransmits car x's message about the black ice with the added info that the southbound lane might not be slick.
car z warns its driver that is approaching GPS pos B and that the northbound lane might be slick.

This could continue on with each car adding information about which lanes a slick.  Car with different findings would not erase each other, just add.

the issues i see here:
protocol for position sensitive information
time sensitive information (the message eventually needs to go away).
ability to add to messages, vehicle voting on slickness etc.

Comment: He covered this, but touched a lot on how to stop people from gaming the system for their own benefit.  Because of this, they are leaning towards placing beacons along highways that will accept and retransmit, allowing firmware upgrades to be placed on the entire system vs having to update every car with it.  But they have the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely ask about security and privacy.  What data about my vehicle is available to another vehicle? etc

Comment: Well that's already available online.  The answer is position and by multiple associations, speed.  No vehicle identification with that data, transmitted to a 300m radius.

Comment: His #2 point, everything is anonymous but in order to use it you'll have to authenticate.  Which he said were opposite concepts, and was an active research area.  #1 was safety.

Answer (score 0):

How do the V2V determine which vehicle to communicate to, expecially at speeds greater than 60 mph?

On a freeway / highway with 5 lanes on each side, during rush hour, how far does the communication go?
Does the V2V communicate with vehicles on the other side of the freeway?

Is GPS considered as part of V2V?

What is the maximum supported distance for V2V?

Can V2V broadcast on Cell-Phone frequencies or FM radio frequencies?

Comment: It's 300 meters point to multipoint communication using standard wireless standards.  They are heavily looking at 802.11p for low latency and high security connections.  GPS is included but they are also looking for higher accuracy systems to augment gps.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask how they are approaching the problem, and in particular if they took current research results from vehicle wireless sensor networks, since that's an area I was researching into when in grad school.

Also some published papers on the actual implementation and experimentation results would be great.

Comment: All technologies are being built upon ieee and established standards already.

Answer (score 0):

Security! What is in place to stop a couple clever teenagers from griefing v2v enables cars with false vehicle positions?  I'm especially wary if the car wants to take control from me (automatic braking, etc).

Comment: Car will probably not take control of the car due to lack of signal confidence for the next few years for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to see this integrated with traction control.  It would be invaluable if oncoming cars broadcast recent moments when they had less traction.

Using this same idea, integrate v2v with radar detectors.  In this case drivers would be more aware of the traffic cop hidden around upcoming corner.

Comment: The traction control option wouldn't buy you too much. Torque, tire type, vehicle drive type, weight, etc. all play a factor. I don't know that you could make anything meaningful out of the data.

Comment: If a particular shady corner to causes the traction control of 15 out of 20 cars to kick in, I'd like to know.  I think it would be particularly useful during winter driving.  I personally drove around a corner on a 2 lane highway where 5 of the 10 cars went into the ditch.  It was sunny and the roads where dry until we came around the corner where it was sheet ice.  Scariest moment driving ever.  I didn't go in the ditch by shear luck,  I didn't hit any of the other cars by shear luck.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's very different than allowing the car to make real-time traction control decsions based off of the data.

Comment: They covered this too.  For a government organization, they seemed on top of things.  Although he said it's all possible technically but it will take 50-100 years to implement due to policy and our 'institutional nature' as a country to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ask if they plan to implement a 'get out of my way' functionality for ambulances etc and how much you need to pay him under the table to get such a box.

Comment: They may not implement get out of my way, but as a basic start they are looking to implement 'here i am' signals.  meaning if you break down, youll send an alert to drivers that there is a broken vehicle in the right lane, move left and watch out.